# VSTO, change size of all pictures in word document to fit page width

Tags: c#, outlook, ms-word, vsto

I'm trying to create an Outlook addin that would take the contents of the currently open email, and save it as a word document. Before saving, it should adjust the sizes of picture, tables etc to fit the page width.

I'm strugling with the resizing part.

After fetching the content of the email as a word document object...

```
var ispector = e.Control.Context as Inspector;
var mailItem = ispector.CurrentItem as MailItem;
var document = ispector.WordEditor as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document;
```

... and getting the available width

```
float availableWidth = document.PageSetup.PageWidth - document.PageSetup.LeftMargin - document.PageSetup.RightMargin;
```

... I'm iterating through shapes, inline shapes and tables to adjust the width.

```
foreach (InlineShape item in document.InlineShapes)
{
   if (item.Width > availableWidth)
      item.Width = availableWidth;
}

foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table table in document.Tables)
{
   table.AllowAutoFit = true;
   table.AutoFitBehavior(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdAutoFitBehavior.wdAutoFitContent);
}
```

But no matter what I do, the pictures in the saved document are not resized.

I even tried to call a Delete method on every shape/inlineshape but still nothing changes in the saved document.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the Outlook part of this, just the Word object model, but... The way I read the code, it's still working in the Email, not an independent Word document? Would it help to save it out as a separate file, first, then work with the graphics in that?

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it worked. After saving and then opening the saved document, everything starts working as expected (resizing, inserting and formatting text etc.). For some reason, manipulating the document before saving/opening, does not work. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Since others could run into this problem, I've written it out as an Answer in the hopes this Q&A will be retained on the site (it will depend on whether they get up-voted or the answer is marked as such). FWIW I don't know the exact "why", I can only guess as to why the editor may not be retaining that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the Email as a Word document, first. Open that and apply the formatting to the pictures.